# How many days before are you allowed to enter the EU with a student visa?

Tags: student-visa

Once issued a student visa for the Schengen countries, how many days prior to the course starting will a student typically be allowed in the country? Is it safe to say, 5 days before? I just applied for a visa and of all goes well, it will be issued very, very close to the course start date. I'd like to arrange a ticket beforehand, it would be cheaper to buy now even with change fees then days before I am supposed to leave! Thanks!!

Comment: Different countries may have different procedures. Please edit your question to indicate which country you've applied to.

Comment: one data point: in france it's a function of when you say you'll be arriving and when you tell them you've booked accomodation from. although in my case it was 4 weeks after my job began, due to delays ;)